# avoid in-between tag to interfere with display:table

Tags: css

I have table-like data containing many forms. Since there are many forms, I cannot use a real table. The table can be seen in a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5ot6rgc4/26/), and also below this lines. My problem are the headings: as you can see, **headers are not in place**. I think the `<form>` tag is ruining the display.

Is there a way to make the `<form>` tag "dimentionless" (not to interfere with the "table")?

PS: it is unimportant to this post, but the table is generated through a SQL query, and the JS collects the data and sends it to a php for being updated in the DB.

```js
function SendFormData(id) {
 TheResult="";
 var TheFormElements=document.getElementById(id).elements;
 for (i=0; i<TheFormElements.length; i++){
   TheResult+=TheFormElements[i].name+": "+TheFormElements[i].value;
    TheResult+="<br>";
 }
  document.getElementById("Results").innerHTML = TheResult;
}
```

```css
.table {
  display:table;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse; 
}
.thead {
  display:table-header-group;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  background-color: #468754;
  color: white; 
}
.tbody {
  display:table-row-group;
}
.tr {
  display:table-row;
}
.td {
  display:table-cell;
  padding:5px;
}

.FormInputClass {
  padding: 6px 10px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
.FormInputClass:focus {
  border: 1px solid #bc6060;
 background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;  
}
.ButtonClass {
 margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: #1b8221;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease; 
}
.ButtonClass:hover {
  background-color: #22c92b;
}
```

```html
<div class="table"> 
    <div class="thead"> 
        <div class="tr"> 
            <div class="td">Date</div> 
            <div class="td">Main Group</div> 
            <div class="td">People</div> 
            <div class="td">Activity</div> 
            <div class="td"></div> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
    <div class="tbody">   
        <form id="One"> 
            <div class="tr" style="background-color:#e4f4d2"> 
                 <div class="td"><input type="date" class="FormInputClass" name="Date" value="2018-10-10"></div> 
                 <div class="td"><input type="text" class="FormInputClass" name="Main" value="MainXX"></div> 
                 <div class="td"><input type="text" class="FormInputClass" name="In_charge" value="Peter"></div> 
                 <div class="td"><input type="text" class="FormInputClass" name="Activity" value="Drawing"></div> 
                 <div class="td"><input type="button" value="Send data" class="ButtonClass" onclick="SendFormData('One');"></div> 
            </div> 
            <div class="tr" style="background-color:#e4f4d2"> 
                 <div class="td"></div> 
                 <div class="td"></div> 
                 <div class="td"><input type="text" class="FormInputClass" name="Helper_1" value="John"></div> 
                 <div class="td"><input type="text" class="FormInputClass" name="Helper_1_Acty" value="Lines"></div> 
                 <div class="td">&nbsp;</div> 
            </div> 
            <div class="tr" style="background-color:#e4f4d2"> 
                 <div class="td"></div> 
                 <div class="td"></div> 
                 <div class="td"><input type="text" class="FormInputClass" name="Helper_2" value="Mary"></div> 
                 <div class="td"><input type="text" class="FormInputClass" name="Helper_2_Acty" value="Lines"></div> 
                 <div class="td"></div> 
            </div>                           
        </form>
        <form id="Two"> 
            <div class="tr" style="background-color:#f9f3d9"> 
                 <div class="td"><input type="date" class="FormInputClass" name="Date" value="2018-11-22"></div> 
                 <div class="td"><input type="text" class="FormInputClass" name="Main" value="MainYY"></div> 
                 <div class="td"><input type="text" class="FormInputClass" name="In_charge" value="Stephen"></div> 
                 <div class="td"><input type="text" class="FormInputClass" name="Activity" value="Controlling"></div> 
                 <div class="td"><input type="button" value="Send data" class="ButtonClass" onclick="SendFormData('Two');"></div> 
            </div> 
            <div class="tr" style="background-color:#f9f3d9"> 
                 <div class="td"></div> 
                 <div class="td"></div> 
                 <div class="td"><input type="text" class="FormInputClass" name="Helper_1" value="Dedalus"></div> 
                 <div class="td"><input type="text" class="FormInputClass" name="Helper_1_Acty" value="writing"></div> 
                 <div class="td"></div> 
            </div> 
            <div class="tr" style="background-color:#f9f3d9"> 
                 <div class="td"></div> 
                 <div class="td"></div> 
                 <div class="td"><input type="text" class="FormInputClass" name="Helper_2" value="James"></div> 
                 <div class="td"><input type="text" class="FormInputClass" name="Helper_2_Acty" value="images"></div> 
                 <div class="td"></div> 
            </div>   
            <div class="tr" style="background-color:#f9f3d9"> 
                 <div class="td"></div> 
                 <div class="td"></div> 
                 <div class="td"><input type="text" class="FormInputClass" name="Helper_3" value="Joyce"></div> 
                 <div class="td"><input type="text" class="FormInputClass" name="Helper_3_Acty" value="Words"></div> 
                 <div class="td"></div> 
            </div>                                              
        </form>              
    </div>
</div>

<div id="Results">
</div>
```

Comment: not using a table for this would be totally semantically incorrect - if you have a look at your page with your css turned off, that is how it would read to a screen reader and would make no sense - would also fail the eu accessibility standards and open you up to being sued.  Why not put a new table in each form but hide the headings of tables after the first form?

Comment: I can dismiss the legal part, since this is part of a non-public web. And about using tables, yes, it can be a solution. I was trying to avoid that since field widths will not be the same (except for fixed width, which I was trying to avoid...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the tbody wrapper div and add the tbody class to each form inside your table. Beside that i would use html table tags instead of divs styled as tables.

```js
function SendFormData(id) {
 TheResult="";
 var TheFormElements=document.getElementById(id).elements;
 for (i=0; i<TheFormElements.length; i++){
   TheResult+=TheFormElements[i].name+": "+TheFormElements[i].value;;
    TheResult+="<br>";
 }
  document.getElementById("Results").innerHTML = TheResult;
}
```

```css
.table {
  display:table;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse; 
}
.thead {
  display:table-header-group;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  background-color: #468754;
  color: white; 
}
.tbody {
  display:table-row-group;
}

.thead .td{
  padding: 10px;
}

.tr {
  display:table-row;
}
.td {
  display:table-cell;
  padding:5px;
}

.FormInputClass {
  padding: 6px 10px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
.FormInputClass:focus {
  border: 1px solid #bc6060;
 background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;  
}
.ButtonClass {
 margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: #1b8221;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease; 
}
.ButtonClass:hover {
  background-color: #22c92b;
}
```

```html
<div class="table"> 
    <div class="thead"> 
        <div class="tr"> 
            <div class="td">Date</div> 
            <div class="td">Main Group</div> 
            <div class="td">People</div> 
            <div class="td">Activity</div> 
            <div class="td"></div> 
        </div> 
    </div>  
        <form id="One" class="tbody"> 
            <div class="tr" style="background-color:#e4f4d2"> 
                 <div class="td"><input type="date" class="FormInputClass" name="Date" value="2018-10-10"></div> 
                 <div class="td"><input type="text" class="FormInputClass" name="Main" value="MainXX"></div> 
                 <div class="td"><input type="text" class="FormInputClass" name="In_charge" value="Peter"></div> 
                 <div class="td"><input type="text" class="FormInputClass" name="Activity" value="Drawing"></div> 
                 <div class="td"><input type="button" value="Send data" class="ButtonClass" onclick="SendFormData('One');"></div> 
            </div> 
            <div class="tr" style="background-color:#e4f4d2"> 
                 <div class="td"></div> 
                 <div class="td"></div> 
                 <div class="td"><input type="text" class="FormInputClass" name="Helper_1" value="John"></div> 
                 <div class="td"><input type="text" class="FormInputClass" name="Helper_1_Acty" value="Lines"></div> 
                 <div class="td">&nbsp;</div> 
            </div> 
            <div class="tr" style="background-color:#e4f4d2"> 
                 <div class="td"></div> 
                 <div class="td"></div> 
                 <div class="td"><input type="text" class="FormInputClass" name="Helper_2" value="Mary"></div> 
                 <div class="td"><input type="text" class="FormInputClass" name="Helper_2_Acty" value="Lines"></div> 
                 <div class="td"></div> 
            </div>                           
        </form>
        <form id="Two" class="tbody"> 
            <div class="tr" style="background-color:#f9f3d9"> 
                 <div class="td"><input type="date" class="FormInputClass" name="Date" value="2018-11-22"></div> 
                 <div class="td"><input type="text" class="FormInputClass" name="Main" value="MainYY"></div> 
                 <div class="td"><input type="text" class="FormInputClass" name="In_charge" value="Stephen"></div> 
                 <div class="td"><input type="text" class="FormInputClass" name="Activity" value="Controlling"></div> 
                 <div class="td"><input type="button" value="Send data" class="ButtonClass" onclick="SendFormData('Two');"></div> 
            </div> 
            <div class="tr" style="background-color:#f9f3d9"> 
                 <div class="td"></div> 
                 <div class="td"></div> 
                 <div class="td"><input type="text" class="FormInputClass" name="Helper_1" value="Dedalus"></div> 
                 <div class="td"><input type="text" class="FormInputClass" name="Helper_1_Acty" value="writing"></div> 
                 <div class="td"></div> 
            </div> 
            <div class="tr" style="background-color:#f9f3d9"> 
                 <div class="td"></div> 
                 <div class="td"></div> 
                 <div class="td"><input type="text" class="FormInputClass" name="Helper_2" value="James"></div> 
                 <div class="td"><input type="text" class="FormInputClass" name="Helper_2_Acty" value="images"></div> 
                 <div class="td"></div> 
            </div>   
            <div class="tr" style="background-color:#f9f3d9"> 
                 <div class="td"></div> 
                 <div class="td"></div> 
                 <div class="td"><input type="text" class="FormInputClass" name="Helper_3" value="Joyce"></div> 
                 <div class="td"><input type="text" class="FormInputClass" name="Helper_3_Acty" value="Words"></div> 
                 <div class="td"></div> 
            </div>                                              
        </form>              
</div>

<div id="Results">
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, thanks!! It's also comforting that changes are so easy implemented. Regarding tables, I will consider your comment,as well as @Pete's. Thanks again.